# Issue trying to use setValue forKey on Realm Object

Tags: swift, realm

I'm writing a few wrapper functions for a Service I'm working on, and hitting a weird issue trying to use setValue forKey on Realm Objects. Object inherits from NSObject so this shouldn't be an issue

```
protocol Saveable {
    associatedtype Object

    // Save a Realm Object from a JSON response
    static func save(item: AnyObject, realm: Realm) -> Object?
}

extension Saveable {
    static func setString(o: Object, field:String, value: String, realm: Realm) {
        try! realm.write {
            o.setValue(value, forKey: field)
        }
    }

    static func setInt(o: KidObject, field:String, value: Int, realm: Realm) {
        try! realm.write {
            o.setValue(value, forKey: field)
        }
    }
}
```

The first method, setString gives me this error:
Value of type 'Self.Object' has no member 'setValue'

The second one works, and there is nothing in KidObject:

```
import RealmSwift

class KidObject: Object {

}
```

Having my models extend KidObject is "fine" but I'd like to understand why this is behaving like this

Thanks!

*Update 05/27/2016 to include the full protocol definition*

Comment: It doesn't reproduce in my environment. Can you show the code of `protocol Saveable`?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi I've updated the post. If I remove the associatedtype line, it will work, but unsure why that causes it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you define `associatedtype Object` in `Saveable` protocol, `associatedtype Object` hides RealmSwift's `Object` type due to conflict name.

If you'd like to identify each `Object` types, you should use `RealmSwift.Object` to represent RealmSwift's `Object` type. Like the following:

```
extension Saveable {
    static func setString(o: RealmSwift.Object, field:String, value: String, realm: Realm) {
        try! realm.write {
            o.setValue(value, forKey: field)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you!